# Check if Workbook_Open is used in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have build a custom excel add-in and I want to check if any workbook which is opened has Workbook_Open event handled already in the workbook. Based on it if already handled I want to prompt the user with some instructions to follow. Below is the code snippet of the method used in ThisWorkbookk of user workbook.

```vb
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Some code user had already written here
    End Sub
```

I already checked ThisWorkbook object, it does not have any property or list of events which are already used.

Is there any way or property to determine if the Open event of workbook is used in User workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that can Check if the `WorkBook_Open` Procedure exists in a Workbook.

- Change the File Name as It is in the Code
- set a reference to the **Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3 Library**

  ```
  Sub Check()

  Dim pk As vbext_ProcKind
  Dim vbProj As VBIDE.VBProject
  Dim vbComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
  Dim vbMod As VBIDE.CodeModule

  Set app = Excel.Application

  For Each vbProj In app.VBE.VBProjects

      If vbProj.filename = "C:\Users\mohit.bansal\Desktop\Test\Faster.xlsm" Then

      For Each vbComp In vbProj.VBComponents

          Set vbMod = vbComp.CodeModule

              iLine = 1
              Do While iLine < vbMod.CountOfLines
                sProcName = vbMod.ProcOfLine(iLine, pk)
                If sProcName <> "" Then
                  'Debug.Print vbComp.Name & ": " & sProcName

                  If sProcName = "Workbook_Open" Then MsgBox "WorkBook_Open Exists!!"

                  iLine = iLine + vbMod.ProcCountLines(sProcName, pk)
                Else
                  iLine = iLine + 1
                End If
              Loop

      Next

      End If

  Next

  End Sub
  ```

Courtesy: [peltiertech](https://peltiertech.com/list-vba-procedures-by-vba-module-and-vb-procedure/)